# Dynamic Displacement for tracks doesn't appear in the final render?

Tags: displacement, dynamic-paint

[image: Image1]
I use the dynamic paint - brush, for the wheel

[image: image2]
and the dynamic paint - canvas for the plane with displacement

[image: This is the preview render]
This is the preview render animation of the tracks

it looks fine,

[image: And this is the final render]
and This is the final render in the same frame of the animation.

So why the final render just appears like a flat plane like that? 
I need some help here, thanks

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project and how you are creating the displacement.

Comment: Did you bake the dynamic paint?

Comment: @JakeD No, I didn't,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have **Subsurf** modifier with different settings for **render** and **viewport**:

[image]

So, then you hit render new plane generates and **dynamic paint** refreshes.

Set **view subdivisions** equal to **render subdivisions**.

Comment: Ooooh Yes! it works, so if i use the subsurface, is it always need to set the view subdivision same as the render divisions, right?

this help me a lot :))) thnks i need to learn more hehe :)

Comment: @MuhammadFakhriHusaini no, not always. Only if it affects modifiers  below in the stack

Comment: oh right, i see, thnks again :))